# Configure Postfix to use port 201

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

I am not a guru of linux and advanced configuration and this might be a silly question but how am I going to configure postfix (smtp) to use port 201 in same time with 25, on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I managed to do something in /etc/postfix/master.cf , at the end of this file I added:

201       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd

It seems that I can connect now but in the Mail Queue I find the following error:

connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection refused

And it's not only for gmail addresses, it doesn't work for any.

If I am going to configure the email client with port 25 at smtp. I don't have this problem.

Seems that I am missing something.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: the error is telling you the problem. eventhough your configured it for port 201 but the client still trying to use port 25. So look at your client instead of postfix.

Comment: I am pretty sure thats not the problem. I am connecting through 201 and I send the email, but the recipients do not receive it.

Comment: Ah then telnet to  gmail smtp port 25. Most ISP blocked port 25.

Comment: This is why I am connecting through 201. Because 25 is blocked. So I am connected to my smtp server but from there the email will remain in the queue instead of being sent.

Comment: How you change port 25 on google server? No you cant. Also you need to authenticate if you want to use google smtp. You also need TLS configured to communicate with google mail server.

Comment: Aizuddin Zali seems that you didn't understood my problem or I didn't explained it enough.

Comment: please try [this.](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/03/06/how-to-change-smtp-port-number-25-in-postfix/)